# WildFly 11 deployment order with jboss-all.xml

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I have a question related to the deployment order with *jboss-all.xml* configuration files.

Let's assume I have 2 files *app.ear* and *framework.ear* deployed in WildFly 11.

*framework.ear* needs to be deployed before *app.ear* which is expressed by the *jboss-all.xml* file contained in the app.ear/META-INF folder:

```
<jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
<jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
     <dependency name="framework.ear" />
</jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

Now something changes in *framework.ear* and a redeployment of *framework.ear* becomes necessary.

**Question**: Why does *app.ear* gets redeployed, too, immediately after a **hot deployment** of *framework.ear* has been carried out?

**Observations**: After the redeployment of *framework.ear* a new *framework.ear.deployed* marker gets created, but same does not hold for *app.ear.deployed*.

In fact no new *app.ear.deployed* gets created at all (same timestamp for this file as before) despite a redeployment takes place.

Nevertheless, in the console I see a redeployment for the dependent *app.ear* occurs.

Extending the example above, this is time consuming when you have a couple of additional dependencies cascading through.

I don't understand why this happens because *app.ear* did not change.

My expectation is that only a redeployment of *framework.ear* will take place. In my opinion there is no reason to redeploy *app.ear*, too.

**Can someone explain to me how to prevent a redeployment of dependent archives when *jboss-all.xml* configuration files are used in conjunction with hot deployments, please?**

Many thanks.

Comment: The correct file is not jboss-deployment-structure.xml ?

Comment: Could you find a solution? I am in the same situation.